# Baby fox, baby lion, baby X

Tags: перевод

I was trying to do an on the spot translation of children's book, that had the phrases, "baby bear, baby whale, baby etc" I wasn't sure because Russian doesn't seem to covert nouns to adjective as easily as English does. So I tried google translate and seemed to get a bunch of possibilities

> I see a baby whale. Baby foxes live with me. I live with baby foxes.
> Baby bears prefer blondes. Baby rabbits never go far from their
> mothers. This is a baby rhinoceros. Baby tigers are delicious. Baby tigers prefer dark meat. The chef boiled the baby tiger.
>
> Я вижу ребенка кита. Детские лисы жить со мной. Я живу с ребенком лис.
> Мишки предпочитают блондинок. Детские кролики не уезжать далеко от
> своих матерей. Это ребенок носорога. Детские тигров восхитительны. Детские тигры предпочитают темное мясо. Повар варил тигренка.

ребенка кита, с ребенком лис and ребенок носорога look wrong, but I don't know why.

Мишки, тигренка - looks okay, but is there really a special word for each kind of baby animal, including, say baby pangolins?

Детские кролики - looks like this means childish rabbit.

(yeah, I know I should quite my job and go learn this at a Uni instead of using google translate, but I got bills to pay)

Comment: The Google translator gives completely incorrect and ungrammatical output.

Comment: @Anixx that wasn't my question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Russian has the names of most baby animals as separate, distinct nouns, they are formed after the following pattern: [the name of the animal] + -ёнок / -онок, the plural is [the name of the animal] + -ята / -ата, both with all the palatalization phenomena in the root,

> лиса - лисёнок (Pl. лисята)
>
> волк - волчонок (Pl. волчата)
>
> медведь - медвежонок (Pl. медвежата)
>
> кот - котёнок (Pl. котята)
>
> рысь - рысёнок (Pl. рысята)
>
> лев - львёнок (Pl. львята)
>
> лягушка - лягушонок (Pl. лягушата)

There are some special cases, when the name of the baby animal is formed from a different root than the name of the adult one:

> корова - телёнок (Pl. телята)
>
> лошадь, конь - жеребёнок (Pl. жеребята)
>
> овца - ягнёнок (Pl. ягнята)
>
> свинья - поросёнок (Pl. поросята)
>
> собака - щенок (Pl. щенки or щенята)
>
> курица - цыплёнок (Pl. цыплята)

For some exotic animals, like rhinoceros or pangolin, there is no noun in -ёнок / -онок, you form the name of the baby animal this way: детёныш + [the name of the animal in Genitive case]. The word `ребёнок` does not apply here, it refers only to human babies and human children, never to animals, `детёныш` is what is used for baby animals. You have got to consult a dictionary of Russian to find out if the word in -ёнок / -онок exists, if it does not, use the детёныш + [the name of the animal in Genitive case] pattern.

> baby rhinoceros - детёныш носорога
>
> baby pangolin - детёныш панголина

The English way of calling babies of big animals 'а calf' (Russian `телёнок`, like elephant calf, whale calf) does not apply in Russian, `телёнок` refers only to the bovine babies.

As for your text, the baby animals' names in it are like this:

> baby whale - китёнок
>
> baby foxes - лисята
>
> baby bears - медвежата
>
> baby rabbits - крольчата
>
> baby rhinoceros - детёныш носорога
>
> baby tiger -  тигрёнок, Pl. тигрята